# Give a zero divisor and an invertible element in $\Bbb Z_2[x] / (x^3 +1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In $\Bbb Z_2[x] / (x^3 +1)$, give a zero divisor and an invertible element different from $1 + (x^3 +1)$.

I found that $\Bbb Z_2[x] / (x^3 +1)$ only has $2^3=8$ elements, but I don't understand what they want to say me when they ask me to give "a zero divisor and an invertible element different from $1 + (x^3 +1)$" (I mean "the different from $1 + (x^3 +1)" part).

Comment: It may help if you write the ring as $\mathbb Z_2[u]$ with $u^3=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a nontrivial zero divisor, note that
$$
x^3 +1 \equiv (x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1) \bmod 2
$$

For a nontrivial unit, note that
$$
x \cdot x^2 = x^3  \equiv 1 \bmod (x^3 +1)
$$

Comment: wow, that was totally revealing. also, could you answer me why does the element $x^3 + x + 1$ (in $\Bbb Z_3 [x]$) is in the equivalent class of 0 in $\Bbb Z_3 [x]/(x^3+1) $? If it's not there, in which equivalent class it is?

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't understand what they want to say me when they ask me to give "a zero divisor and an invertible element different from $1 + (x^3 +1)$" (I mean "the different from $1 + (x^3 +1)$" part).

It sounds like they want:

1. An example of two nonzero elements, $a,b$ such that $ab=0$
2. An example of elements $x,y$ such that $xy=1$, but you are not allowed to use $1+(x^3+1)$, which is obviously its own inverse.

So... work to find those!